# Adding nested arrays to a Sequelize/PostgreSQL database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, redux, sequelize.js

I am building a React app with a PostgreSQL database, created with a Sequelize model. In this database I want to store an array of arrays containing two numbers each, but I can't figure out how to go about this.

The app I'm building is a snakes and ladders type game, that generates a new board for every game. The snakes and ladders (in my case 'pits' and 'portals') are rendered from this array I told you about, the pairs of numbers represent the numbers of the entrance and exit.

I tried passing the array datatype as an argument to itself, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there another way I can make this work?

The dataset I would like to store in this column would look a little something like this:

```
[
[15, 4], 
[34, 21], 
[42, 19], 
[56, 48], 
[72, 30], 
[82, 63], 
[97, 71]
]
```

This is how I tried to achieve this in my Sequelize model:

```
  pits: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER))
  }
```

Obviously this didn't go the way I planned, or I wouldn't be bothering you guys with this. I hope someone can explain why this doesn't work and help me either fix my database to support this type of data or (quickly) get around this another way. I am aware that this is probably a horrible, worst practices way to store data and can think of multiple ways to fix the issue, but all of them involve rewriting a big portion of my code and require more time than I have at this point.

Please note I have only been coding for under two months and using Sequelize/Postgres for about 2 weeks, so be gentle. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
pits: {
    type: Sequelize.JSONB // allow to save any json
    validate: {
      isValidFormat(value) {
        if (/* add validation if value has correct format (array of array ) */) {
          throw new Error('Bad value');
        }
      },
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey can you please explain inValidFormat function ?

Comment: It's the custom function for validation. The more predefined function here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html